# mysql select top users problem

Tags: mysql

i have `users` table and i have `posts` table i want select from `users` the top users that have the big amount of posts from `posts` table and order them by numbers of posts
i can make it by `array_count_values()` by i cant order it
now i think if i make it by one mysql query by left and join will be more better

**table structure**

```
posts
```

id | auther_id

i tried this

```
SELECT COUNT(1) cnt, u.user_id 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN posts p
ON p.author_id=u.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 20
```

---

it gave me this
[alt text http://img511.imageshack.us/img511/6707/31154352.gif](http://img511.imageshack.us/img511/6707/31154352.gif)
see the arrow
what is this
i just have 2 posts under user_id 5
what is this first row

Comment: what do your tables look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to aggregate the posts by user using GROUP BY u.user_id, get a COUNT value for the number of posts and ORDER BY that number, in descending order:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) cnt, u.user_id 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN posts p
ON p.author_id=u.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: i think it has error its give me the count of users and posts

Comment: You have to include the number of posts to sort by it. Don't you want the count of posts by each user?

Comment: It gives you the count of posts for each of the top 20 users and their user_id

Comment: its give me this row 1 cnt=15 id=2 row 2 (the thing i want) cnt=2 id=5
and i just have 2 posts under 5 user id

Comment: Hello I am here. The first row is 15 posts for user id 2. cnt is the number of posts, id is the user id.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT u.user_id, COUNT(*) as post_count
FROM   users u
INNER JOIN posts p
USING (user_id)
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER BY post_count
```

Answer (score 0):

i used this and its worked
is it true

```
SELECT COUNT( 1 ) cnt, a.auther_id
FROM `posts` a
LEFT JOIN users u ON a.auther_id = u.id
GROUP BY a.auther_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 20
```